# How to find a specific meta tag

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to retrieve a meta tag (Tag name=Generator) using Jsoup parser in java.

The code I have is given below:

```
Elements metalinks=doc.select("meta"); // meta

boolean metafound=false;
for (Element singlemeta : metalinks) 
{
    metatagname = singlemeta.attr("abs:name");
    metatagcontent = singlemeta.attr("abs:content");
    if((metatagname=="Generator")||(metatagname=="generator")||(metatagname=="GENERATOR")){
        //  this is the tag we want to get value of...
        metarequired=metatagcontent;
        metafound=true;
    }
}   
if(metafound==false)
    metarequired="NOT_FOUND";
```

However I am unable to extract the meta `GENERATOR` tag correctly.

One example of this tag is now given below:

```
<meta name="generator" content="Test page" />
```

For the very first line in code given above, I also tried the following code but that also does not work:

```
//Elements metalinks= doc.getElementsByTag("meta");
```

How do I extract the meta tag correctly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It almost looks as if you're making it too complicated. What if you started out with something simple like this:

```
Elements metalinks = doc.select("meta[name=generator]");
```

Comment: ... and if you want to select the content from the tag then `metalinks.select("content").first().toString()`

Comment: @SYLARRR: you are wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296520/how-to-extract-the-content-attribute-of-the-meta-name-generator-tag

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft, I'm using it to extract OpenGraph tags, and that's the best way to go.


        Elements metaOgTitle = doc.select("meta[property=og:title]");
        Elements metaOgTitle = doc.select("meta[property=og:image]");