# How to extract the content attribute of the meta name=generator tag?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using the below code to extract meta 'generator' tag content from a web page using Jsoup:

```
Elements metalinks = doc.select("meta[name=generator]");
boolean metafound=false;

if(metalinks.isEmpty()==false)
{ 
    metatagcontent = metalinks.first().select("content").toString();
    metarequired=metatagcontent;
    metafound=true;
}
else 
{
    metarequired="NOT_FOUND";
    metafound=false;
}
```

The problem is that for a page that does contain the meta generator tag, no value is shown (when I output the value of variable 'metarequired'. For a page that does not have meta generator tag, the value 'NOT_FOUND' is shown correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your code,

```
metalinks.first().select("content").toString();
```

This is not correct. This is merely selecting

```html
<meta ...>
    <content ... /> <!-- This one, which of course doesn't exist. -->
</meta>
```

while you *actually* want to get the attribute

```html
<meta ... content="..." />
```

You need to use [`attr("content")`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`select("content")`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29).

```
metatagcontent = metalinks.first().attr("content");
```

#### See also:

- [Jsoup cookbook - Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [W3 CSS3 selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you don't need to test against a `boolean` inside an `if` block. The `isEmpty()` **already** returns a `boolean`:

```
if (!metalinks.isEmpty())
```

Comment: You're welcome. For future selector issues, please read the "See also" links. It contains lot of valuable examples.